# Find out which table a column in a view is from (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-view

I have a SQL view which unions 2 tables together, using a UNION ALL.

I'm writing a stored procedure to update a boolean value, and due to the presence of the union obviously cannot update the view itself.  So I'm trying to find the best way to determine which table the row of data came from, and will then update that table directly.

Is there a SYS table or the like which can be used to find this out?

Comment: If you're using `UNION` (rather than `UNION ALL`) then a single output row may have originated from multiple tables.

Comment: That is true, however in this case I could and probably should be using a UNION ALL. Duplicate rows aren't an issue. I'll update the question - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in a column to differentiate between the two tables:

For example:

```
SELECT table1ID, table1Values...etc, 'table1' As OriginatingTable FROM table1
UNION
SELECT table2ID, table2Values...etc, 'table2' As OriginatingTable FROM table2
```

Then in your stored procedure, to identify which table to update, simply check the column value for OriginatingTable.

Comment: So simple! Thanks very much, will mark as the answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

In the clauses that are being union-ed, you could add another column that names the source table, and reference that in your stored procedure.